How to fix? Rust: Syntax Error: expected IN_KW
I am new to Rust. I come from a low level, low power, microcontroller C background (not C++) and PCB Design. I am trying to learn Rust by going through "The Rust Programming Language" interactive book. I am right now at the end of Chapter 3 - Flow Control. There are some practice tasks to practice Rust, and one of the tasks is:
Print the lyrics to the Christmas carol “The Twelve Days of Christmas,” taking advantage of the repetition in the song.
This is my code (not tested yet, need to fix errors first):
fn main() {
    let numbering: [&str; 12] = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth", "seventh", "eighth", "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh", "twelveth"];
    let gifts: [&str; 12] = ["A partridge in a pear tree", "Two turtle doves", "Three French hens", "Four calling birds", "Five golden rings", "Six geese a-laying", "Seven swans a-swimming", "Eight maids a-milking", "Nine ladies dancing", "Ten lords a-leaping", "Eleven pipers piping", "Twelve drummers drumming,"];
    
    for i: u8 in 0..12 {
        println!("On the {} day of Christmas,\n\r my true love sent to me", numbering[i]);
        for j: u8 in 0..i.rev() { 
            println!("{}", gifts[j]);
        }
    }
}

On the both for loops, I am getting "Syntax Error: expected IN_KW" and on the inside of those loops, I am getting "cannot find value 'i/j' in this scope".

This may be because I lack knowledge as I am currently in the first part of the book. Maybe it is something trivial. Please let me know!
I am using VSCode for programming. Using usize on the i: and j: gives error on .rev() (cannot do .rev() on usize).
Also, I cannot just use
 for i in 0..12

As autocomplete in Rust Analyzer (?) puts :usize there if I do not put anything

You don't actually even want u8 here since you only use it as a slice index (which needs a usize).

It isn't "autocomplete in Rust Analyzer" that is showing : usize after i or j, it's inlay hints, and they're not real code, but just virtual text hints that show you what type is inferred for the variables.

Thank you both!
Not sure why the -1 score... Just trying to learn...

Your error is actually that you try to do:
for j in 0..i.rev()

But you must do
for j in (0..i).rev()

After that, you don't need u8.
Apart from that, there is NO such syntax
for i:u8 in 0..12

Instead you can specify the type of the literal, and Rust will infer all other types
for i in 0..12_u8


Thank you! Learning as I go :) Thanks a lot!
